# Divide between two rows of the same column and store the answer in a already existing column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table in my database that has columns 'price', 'percentage' and 'ID'.
Percentage column needs to be calculated using colum 'price' and 'id'.   There is an initial price, followed by three increased prices, all of them having the same ID. I need to find a method that calculates the percentage column in my database using C#.

I attach a picture for better understanding how it should be.
I am writing an import system using Linq and I have already imported all the columns, but now I need to calculate percentage for the increasing prices and I am really struggeling with this. Maybe someone have some god suggestions of how I can solve this.

[image]

UPDATE:

```
public static void calculateProcentage(string id, double price, double, double percentage)
{

    var percentageQuery = from l in db.Table
                          where l.ID == id
                            && l.Price == price && l.Percentage != percentage
                          select l;

    foreach (Table l in percentageQuery)
    {
        //double newPercentage = (double) l.Percentage;

        //DataTable table = new DataTable();
        // int rowCount = table.Rows.Count;
        DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (l.Building_vigor_ID == building_vigor_id)
            {
                //var priceRows = db.V_Leases.Select(x => x.Price_sqm).ToList(); 
                // get a list of the rows of the price column

                // get a list of the rows of the price column
                var priceRows = (from r in db.Table
                                 select r.Price).ToList();

                percentage = (double)(priceRows[i] / priceRows[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    try
    {
        db.SubmitChanges();
        Console.Write("Percentage updated");
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.Write("Could not update percentage");
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

That is what I have tried. I bassicaly wanted to make it like an update method with only updating column percentage. But did not actualy work. I am pretty new with Linq sow it may be some bad code written here.

Comment: Can you show your code so far please?

Comment: Please add what you have done/tried so far

Comment: Are all percentages positive and that how you determine what *order* the rows come in?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever *increased prices* tends to say all percentages are indeed positive, so you have to order rows by id and then by price

Comment: What exactly is your problem ? Do you want to update all rows once, or do you want to calculate the percentage every time you add/edit one row ?

Comment: @Rafalon - when people describe their problems here, they frequently describe the *common* case and neglect to mention corner cases - that's why I'm asking for confirmation on this. I.e. it could easily be that prices *normally* increase but occasionally decrease and in fact we need an additional column that defines the ordering to actually make this work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed you're right, we'll have to wait for the OP's answer

Comment: The prices will only increase maximum three time, and I need it to update every time a new row iti is added. Prices will only increase, never decrease.

Comment: **Your numbers are incorrect**. 19.79 (rounded) is **3%** more than 19.21. This means that I would expect the percentage column to contain either `3` (expressed in %) or `0.03` (expressed as a decimal). Your usage of `0.3` doesn't make sense, this would mean either 0.3% or 30%, not 3%)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should have been 3 expressed in percentage...the picure was just for better understandig about what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The disclaimer

> I am pretty new with Linq sow it may be some bad code written here.

Your question, and the way you've attempted to solve this, are fraught with inconsistencies and seemingly contradictory expectations.

As it stands, the question you've asked is not answerable due to lack of information. However, I do think I understand what the **actual** problem is that you're trying to solve, so I'll give you that answer. But first, let me explain how I've interpreted your question.

---

### My assumptions about your actual question

As I understand it, you're trying to calculate the percentage based on the **previous** value.

A more generalized example:

```
PRICE     %         ID
------------------------
 100      A         1
 103      B         1
 100      C         2
 150      D         2
```

- **A** and **C** should both be **0** as they are the "base" price of their respective ID value.
- **B** should be **3%** because its price is **103%** of A's price.
- **D** should be **50%** because its price is **150%** of C's price.

My below answer will assume that this is correct.

---

There is also a problem with your expected values. In your example, you have listed the percentage of 19.79 (compared to 19.21) as **0.3**.
This does not make sense. The difference is **3%**. There are two different (acceptable) ways to denote this in the percentage column:

1. `3`, because it is expressed as a percentage (**3**%)
2. `0.03`, because it is expressed as a decimal value (3% = **0.03**)

Your usage of `0.3` makes no sense, as I would interpret this as either **0.3%** (option 1) or **30%** (option 2).

In order to maintain consistency, my answer will assume that you want the **decimal value** (`0.03` in the above example)

---

I assume your data class is constructed as follows:

```
public class Foo
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

---

I don't quite understand how you're using the method. You supply three parameters (`string id, double price, double, double percentage`), but then you go on to select your data as follows:

```
var percentageQuery = from l in db.Table
                      where l.ID == id
                        && l.Price == price && l.Percentage != percentage
                      select l;
```

It makes little sense to supply a percentage, and then pick everything that's **different** from that percentage. You have no idea of knowing what data you're going to get, in what order, and whether or not the found entries are "before" or "after" your mentioned percentage.

Instead, my answer will be a method that **recalculates all percentages of a given ID**. This seems like a much clearer algorithm.

---

### The assumed answer

**Retrieving the data**

Your attempt is a weird mix of new and old technologies (LINQ, DataTable), I'm going to use LINQ near exclusively, as I feel the use of `DataTable` is unwarranted here.

```
public static void CalculatePercentagesForID(int id)
{
    Foo[] rows = db.Table.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToArray();
    
    //... (see the next code block)
}
```

This is much simpler. Note that I am assuming that you wish to process the entries based on the **order** that they appear in the database. If you need to order them based on something else (e.g. a date value in your `Foo` objects), then you will have to use an additional `OrderBy`, e.g. :

```
Foo[] rows = db.Table.Where(x => x.ID == id).Orderby(x => x.DateCreated).ToArray();
```

**Processing the data**

It's important to notice here that a percentage is calculated off of **two** (subsequent) rows.

```
//The first entry is always the "base" price, therefore always 0.
rows[0].Percentage = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    var previous = rows[i-1];
    var current = rows[i];

    current.Percentage = CalculateDifferenceInPercentage(previous.Price, current.Price);
}

//TODO: save all the objects in "rows" back to the database!
```

Notice how the `for` loop starts at 1, not at 0. We skip step 0 because the first element is automatically 0 anyway. The `for` loop will only process every row **after** the first.

**Calculating the percentage**

```
public static Decimal CalculateDifferenceInPercentage(decimal oldPrice, decimal newPrice)
{
    //1.The elaborate calculation 
    
    //The comments are example output when oldPrice = 19.21, newPrice = 19.79
    
    var theRatio = newPrice / oldPrice;              
    // = 1.0301...
    
    var theRatioRounded = Math.Round(theRatio,2);    
    // = 1.03
    
    var thePercentageDifference = theRatioRounded - 1;
    // = 0.03
    
    return thePercentageDifference;
}
```

Or, if you want a shorter (but harder to read) version:

```
public static Decimal CalculateDifferenceInPercentage(decimal oldPrice, decimal newPrice)
{
    return Math.Round(newPrice / oldPrice , 2) - 1;
}
```

---

### Some caveats

- I've omitted some null-checks for the sake of simplicity, e.g. checking if any rows are returned.
- I've omitted how to save the updated entities in the database as it is not pertinent to your actual question about **calculating the percentages**.
- This works both for negative and positive percentages.

Comment: This is realy helpfull! Thank you for your suggestions. I will take into consideration your remarks when I will ask a question again.